# Installing Chez Scheme 9.4 on Linux Mint LMDE

Tags: linux, scheme, x11, linux-mint, chez-scheme

I am trying to install [Chez Scheme 9.4](https://cisco.github.io/ChezScheme/#community) on a Linux Mint LMDE system. Chez Scheme requires GNU make, gcc, header files and libraries for ncurses, and header files and libraries for X windows.

I successfully installed ncurses with the command `sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev`, and I have a directory `/etc/X11` with lots of stuff in it. Per the Chez Scheme BUILDING file I ran `./configure`, which worked properly, then `sudo make install`, which failed with error `X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory`.

I'm not familiar with X windows. Can someone please tell me exactly what packages I need to install to have the required X windows header files and libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev` and the compile completed successfully.